# How to allow only for 180 degrees of autorotation?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, autorotate

For my iPad app, I intend to disable autorotation. However I heard that apple will reject the app as they expect the app to at least be able to rotate 180 degrees. Has anyone experienced this before? Any truth in this?

In any case, can anyone advise me on how I can set the autorotation to only for portrait mode? i.e. only allow rotation of 180 degrees.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Zhen

Comment: "Has anyone experienced this before?" It appears the answer is yes: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45376-ipad-app-rejected-due-autorotation-problems.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view controller, override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: Or simpler to write, `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, if you simply set the BOOL to No in shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation. I have seen tones of other gaming apps that allow only Landscape or Portrait though, so 180 degree at least, I guess.